# How to obtain input like these in python? with multiple line and conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, user-input

Input:
Zantro@16.15 Zity@12.5 Gamry@9.8

Output conditions:

The name and mileage of certain cars are passed as input. The format is CARNAME@MILEAGE and the input is as a single line, with each car information separated by a space. The program must print the car with the lowest mileage.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not code writing service. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4046632

Comment: please include your code which you are trying to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function to seperate `carnames` and `mileage` and compare.

```
s = input().split(" ")
d = {}
l = []
for data in s:
    value, key = data.split("@")
    d[key] = value
    l.append(float(key))

print(d[str(min(l))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, here is the spoon I am feeding you with:

So you take the input split on every space character.

```
entries = the_input.split() # str.split with no arg splits on whitespace
```

Now you have a list of "Car@Number".
Loop over that, split by "@" symbol.

```
 car_name, mileage = entry.split("@")
 mileage = float(mileage) # parse the string into a floating point number
```

Note: you want to loop entries and put each into List you create earlier, for instance: `complete_entries`, like so

```
complete_entries.append((car_name, mileage))
```

to fill the list with `tuples` of `(car_name, mileage)`

then you can do

```
print(sorted(complete_entries, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

To print a new `sorted` list where `key` is the `lambda` function that takes one parameter `x` and indexes the seconds element of x (`x[1]`) which corresponds to the `mileage` field of the tuple.